# Ajax -- cannot make the data to be sent as "x-www-form-urlencoded"

Tags: javascript, ajax

Although I've specified the content type, `XMLHttpRequest` keeps sending the data in `multipart/form-data`:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'url', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
  //..........

//..........
xhr.send(new FormData("my_form"));
```

because in Chrome dev tools I see this:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryfdsfdsfdsfds
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name1"

something1
------WebKitFormBoundaryfdsfdsfdsfds
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name2"

something2
------WebKitFormBoundaryfdsfdsfdsfds
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name3"

something3
```

which is `multipart/form-data`

No jquery.

Comment: does [Sending POST data with a XMLHttpRequest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/sending-post-data-with-a-xmlhttprequest) help?

Comment: @JaromandaX, no because I use FormData.

Comment: well then read [Using FormData objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Using_FormData_objects) - which states that `The transmitted data is in the same format that the form's submit() method would use to send the data if the form's encoding type were set to "multipart/form-data"`

Comment: @JaromandaX, in my form encoding type isn't set to "multipart/form-data"

Comment: @Mook — *would use to send the data **if** the form's encoding type **were** set to [that]*

Comment: did you read the second link? did you read Quentin's answer? ... using `FormData` results in `Content-Type = multipart/form-data` - there's no way around it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/):

> **FormData**
>   Let the request entity body be the result of running the multipart/form-data encoding algorithm with data as form data set and with utf-8 as the explicit character encoding.

Consequently `FormData` will **always** encode data using the multipart encoding. There is nothing you can do about that other than to construct your `x-www-form-urlencoded` string with your own code (i.e. to not use `FormData`).

Comment: @Mook — Because the specification, *which I quoted in the answer*, says so explicitly.